# python kivy NameError: name '_name_' is not defined

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if _name_ == "_main_":
    MyApp().run()
```

`NameError: name '_name_' is not defined`

This error appears both with single and double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `if __name__ == "__main__":` for running a python file. `__name__` is predefined in python core and you should use exactly that syntax in your code.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```